# How do I correct the error "cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string'" in ' qual.employee_id = recruitment.employee_id; '?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hide   Copy Code

```
public class QualificationService
{
    public void SaveQualificationDetails(RecruitmentViewModel recruitment)
    {
        Qualification qual = new Qualification();
        qual.Employee_Id = recruitment.Employee_Id;
        qual.University = recruitment.University;
        qual.Highest_Qualification = recruitment.Highest_Qualification;
        qual.Specialization = recruitment.Specialization;
        qual.GradeResult = recruitment.GradeResult;
        qual.CV = recruitment.CV;
        qual.Application_Later = recruitment.Application_Later;
        qual.Recomendation_Later = recruitment.Recomendation_Later;

        using (HRMSEntities qualContext = new HRMSEntities())
        {
            qualContext.Qualification.Add(qual);
            qualContext.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Make them the same type or use `.ToString()`

Comment: If it won't implicitly convert, then you need to explicitly convert. Usually you need to compare as strings (because the string may not be a number). Which is the string and which is the number? Convert the number to a string

Comment: Or fix the two to be the same type if you possibly can. Why is `Qualification.Employee_Id` a string, if employee IDs are integers? (I'd also suggest following .NET naming conventions, which would rename `Employee_Id` to `EmployeeId` etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `Object.ToString()`:

```
qual.Employee_Id = recruitment.Employee_Id.ToString();
```

Comment: Faizan Rabbani, i have no words for my thanks... it works.

Comment: @Fira you should consider advises from Jon Skeet as well, if possible make the type of Id same and embrace the naming conventions of a language you are working in. Last but not the least accept the answer as correct if useful.