# It show an error "operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'int' " in "where(x => x.person_id == id)"

Tags: c#

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult EmployeeView(int id)
    {
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        using (HRMSEntities employeeContext = new HRMSEntities())
        {
            employee = employeeContext.Employee.Where(x => x.Person_Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
        }
        return View(employee);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the `Employee` class definition?

Comment: please format your code

Comment: And what is the type of `Person.Person_Id`? According to the error message it is a string. Why should a comparison between a string and an int work? Or: Why do you store an integer value in a string?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I correct the error "cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string'" in ' qual.employee\_id = recruitment.employee\_id; '?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49049116/how-do-i-correct-the-error-cannot-implicitly-convert-type-int-to-string-in)

Answer (score 0):

Try `id.ToString()`, if that doesn't work :

`string idAsString = id.ToString();`

and then `x => x.Person_Id == idAsString`

Answer (score 0):

Main issue would be that you probably shouldn't be storing something that you expect to be an integer value as a string. Other than that, here's some options:

`x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Person_Id) == id`

`x => x.Person_Id == id.ToString()`