# how to fix the error 'cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int? in int latestId = employeeDetails.Person_Id;

Tags: c#

```
namespace HRMS.Models.Service
{
    public class EmployeeService
    {
        public void SaveEmployeeDetails(EmployeeViewModel employee)
        {
            Employee employeeDetails = new Employee();

            employeeDetails.First_Name = employee.First_Name;
            employeeDetails.Father_Name = employee.Father_Name;
            employeeDetails.G_Father_Name = employee.G_Father_Name;
            employeeDetails.Mothers_Full_Name = employee.Mothers_Full_Name;
            employeeDetails.Religion = employee.Religion;
            employeeDetails.Sex = employee.Sex;
            employeeDetails.Birth_Date = employee.Birth_Date;
            employeeDetails.Birth_Place = employee.Birth_Place;
            employeeDetails.Marital_Status = employee.Marital_Status;
            employeeDetails.Nation = employee.Nation;
            employeeDetails.Nationality = employee.Nationality;
            employeeDetails.Medical_Fitness = employee.Medical_Fitness;
            employeeDetails.Registered_Date = employee.Registered_Date;
            employeeDetails.Job_Place = employee.Job_Place;
            employeeDetails.Department = employee.Department;
            employeeDetails.Position = employee.Position;
            employeeDetails.Rank = employee.Rank;
            employeeDetails.Step = employee.Step;
            employeeDetails.Salary = employee.Salary;
            employeeDetails.Status = employee.Status;
            employeeDetails.Remark = employee.Remark;



            using (HRMSEntities employeeContext = new HRMSEntities())
            {
                employeeContext.Employee.Add(employeeDetails);
                employeeContext.SaveChanges();

            }
            int latestId = employeeDetails.Person_Id;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please, help me

Comment: The solution is related to your other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49050604/it-show-an-error-operator-cannot-be-applied-to-operands-of-type-string-a  - Why is Person_Id a string and why do you think you can assign it to an `int`?

Comment: ok, but i tried...it didn't work bro

Comment: Possible duplicate of [It show an error "operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'int' " in "where(x => x.person\_id == id)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49050604/it-show-an-error-operator-cannot-be-applied-to-operands-of-type-string-a)

Comment: Maybe change person_id into an int?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I correct the error "cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string'" in ' qual.employee\_id = recruitment.employee\_id; '?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49049116/how-do-i-correct-the-error-cannot-implicitly-convert-type-int-to-string-in)

Answer (score 1):

`employeeDetails.Person_Id` is a string and you are trying to assign it to an int variable

You either need to change latestId to a string as well

```
string latestId = employeeDetails.Person_Id;
```

or you need to convert to int (as long as you're sure that Person_Id actually holds an integer value)

```
int latestId = Convert.ToInt32(employeeDetails.Person_Id);
```